# How to auto increment the year in javascript datepicker when the date reaches end of the year

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

How to auto increment the year in javascript datepicker when the date reaches end of the year.
My date field displays only maxDate as Current date and yearRange is set to 1900-2022 but it should automatically increment to 2023 once it reaches Dec'31 2022.

```
$('#contractDate').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date,
            yearRange: "1900:2022"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built in date system to get the current year inested of hard codding it

```
$('#contractDate').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date,
            yearRange: "1900:" + new Date().getFullYear()  });
```

if you run this code now the year range would be `1900:2022` in new year it'll be `1900:2023`